# slack actions attributes documentation

Tags: message, slack, slack-api, interactive

From the Slack Interactive Message button sample, it shows the possible attributes are name, text, type, value, style, confirm.

Can someone please point me where I can find the documentation or api guide that show other attributes and possible values for style etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to the official Slack documentation on

- [Interactive Buttons](https://api.slack.com/interactive-messages) concept
- [Field Guide](https://api.slack.com/docs/interactive-message-field-guide) describing all possible    values

I can strongly recommend taking the time to read through and make yourself familiar with the [official Slack documentation](https://api.slack.com/). Its really good and will answer all basic questions like this one.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why it did not occur to me that Field Guide is what I needed.

Comment: Np. If this answer solved your question please consider marking it as such, so that this question can be closed. thank you.